# How do I allow my ListView to fill the entire screen in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I'm making a listview in android, and my listview doesn't fill the entire screen. It has some remaining plain space below the listview (probably because i don't have enough items to fill the screen). I've searched for many solutions online, but none seem to be able to solve this problem.

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ListActivity">

 <ListView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id = "@+id/customListview">

 </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my item_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id= "@+id/ItemNameSales"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Item Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id= "@+id/ItemNameQty"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Item Quantity"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show your adapter item xml view pls

Comment: @VladislavShcherbakov done! pls take a look! :)

Comment: and R.layout.item_layout xml pls

Comment: @VladislavShcherbakov I've added it in!

Comment: You can use android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp" (or more dp), but it is a bad way, let me think more

Comment: At item_layout.xml change all android:layout_height to "wrap_content" and  android:layout_width to "match_parent"

Comment: @MilosLulic i don't think width is affected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change it dinamically to fit the intire screen!!!

```
list.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, CalculateHowYouNeedToFitScreen));
```

Comment: FILL_PARENT is deprecated!

Comment: @MilosLulic change it

Comment: @RodrigoGontijo what do u mean calculate how you need to fit screen?

Comment: @RodrigoGontijo I typed this after the listview.setadapter(adapter):  'listView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 9));' and everything disappeared from the screen...

Comment: @Shells you need to calculate the height of the screen minus the current size of your listView! Then, you put this value replacing "CalculateHowYouNeedToFitScreen"!
But remember, as another user said, it is a bad pratice coding.

Comment: @RodrigoGontijo Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your ListView is already fill entire screen problem is that you dont have have enaf items in list. Another thing that you shoud do is to create holder class to prevant ListView loose list order.You can change dinamicly widht and height of item to fill screen but that is bad practices in coding

```
   View itemView = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (itemView == null) {

     itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.YOURVIEW,parent,false);
     holder = new ViewHolder();
     itemView.setTag( holder );
    }else {
     holder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
    }
     SalesItemInformationLV iteminfo = item.get(position);

     holder.something = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ItemNameSales);

     public class ViewHolder{

      public TextView something;
    }
```